# How to disable all buttons under a class in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am doing a web based game project, where I would like to disable all buttons after 6 different button clicks. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: `[...document.getElementsByTagName('button')].forEach((el)=>el.disabled = true);` is a dense one liner that disables all buttons on the DOM if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select all elements matching your parameters, then disable them one-by-one.

I'm not 100% on by "under a class" you mean a descendant or having the class, so I'll include both.

If you mean a descendant (like `div.className div button`), you can use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.className button').forEach(elem => {
  elem.disabled = true;
});
```

If you meant a button that has a class (like `button.className`), you can use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.className').forEach(elem => {
    elem.disabled = true;
});
```

Of course, you'll still need to keep track of how many times the buttons are pressed, but without more information, that's as much help as we can give.